# Can colorless mana be generated from things that say "Add one mana of any color to your mana pool"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can colorless mana be generated from things that say "Add one mana of any color to your mana pool"?

One example card would be [Coalition Relic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209158).

Reasons:

- For example for sunburst spells, when the caster wants less of the sunburst effect, for whatever reason.
- You need to win the game with Scrapyard Salvo this turn, but you're one artifact in your graveyard short - casting a Sunburst creature as a 0/0 could be your only out

Comment: In what circumstance are you envisaging that it would matter for your mana to be specifically colourless, out of interest?

Comment: @thesunneversets For example for sunburst spells, when the caster wants less of the sunburst effect, for whatever reason

Comment: If you can get Sunburst at all, can't you just use your "add one mana of any colour" ability to add a colour you've already used?  Genuinely curious and not dissing the original question - Magic is the sort of game where there *must* be a corner case where it'd be better for your mana to be colourless, I just couldn't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: You can create sunburst 0 (don't ask me why anyone would want to do that) with only colorless mana, so if you need the "any color" mana to cast the spell at all, you would need to be able to pick colorless. After half an hour of brain torturing and gatherer fiddling, that's the only thing I can come up with.

Comment: Let's suppose you need to win the game with Scrapyard Salvo this turn, but you're one artifact in your graveyard short - casting a Sunburst creature as a 0/0 could be your only out.  Tortuous!  But possible.

Comment: @thesunneversets - In this case, I am specifically thinking about a colorless EDH deck. There are a relatively limited number of 0 cost colorless-identity cards that produce mana, but a much higher number if the cards in this question could be used.

Comment: @cdeszaq - If that is the case, you can still use cards like this.  In EDH (Commander) any color mana added to you mana pool that is outside your commander's color identity will be converted to colorless.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - I just posted a question to answer exactly that :) Go add this comment as an answer

Comment: @thesunneversets, However, this question is still relevant to non-EDH decks as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it cannot.

> **105.4.** If a player is asked to choose a color, he or she must choose one of the five colors. "Multicolored" is not a color. Neither is "colorless."